# Spring boot Native Graalvm + Redis Error creating bean RedisConnection

Tags: spring-boot, redis, graalvm, lettuce, spring-native

I am building spring boot native app with redis.

```
named: systemparam.
spring boot 3.1,
gradle 
lettuce as connection factory
graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.2
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.hibernate.orm' version '6.2.2.Final'
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.20'
}

group = 'id.pgd'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

hibernate {
    enhancement {
        lazyInitialization true
        dirtyTracking true
        associationManagement true
    }
}
```

i successfully build and compile to native but keep getting error bean when trying to run the executable

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManager' parameter 4: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnection': null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:315) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArguments(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:258) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.get(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:198) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[systemparam.exe:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[systemparam.exe:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[systemparam.exe:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[systemparam.exe:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[systemparam.exe:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[systemparam.exe:3.1.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnection': null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RegisteredBean.resolveAutowiredArgument(RegisteredBean.java:219) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:312) ~[na:na]
23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder$1.provider(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:150) ~[na:na]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder$1.<init>(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:130) ~[na:na]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder.<clinit>(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:128) ~[na:na]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.unixDefault(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:117) ~[na:na]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.platformDefault(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:113) ~[na:na]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.<init>(DnsNameResolverBuilder.java:61) ~[na:na]
at io.lettuce.core.resource.AddressResolverGroupProvider$DefaultDnsAddressResolverGroupWrapper.<clinit>(AddressResolverGroupProvider.java:56) ~[na:na]
at io.lettuce.core.resource.AddressResolverGroupProvider.<clinit>(AddressResolverGroupProvider.java:35) ~[na:na]
at io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources.<clinit>(DefaultClientResources.java:112) ~[systemparam.exe:6.2.4.RELEASE]
at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.<init>(AbstractRedisClient.java:122) ~[systemparam.exe:6.2.4.RELEASE]
at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.<init>(RedisClient.java:99) ~[systemparam.exe:6.2.4.RELEASE]
at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.create(RedisClient.java:136) ~[systemparam.exe:6.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.lambda$createClient$7(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1178) ~[systemparam.exe:3.1.0]
at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[systemparam.exe:na]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.createClient(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1178) ~[systemparam.exe:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:324) ~[systemparam.exe:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[systemparam.exe:6.0.9]
35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.base@17.0.7/sun.net.dns.ResolverConfigurationImpl.stringToList(ResolverConfigurationImpl.java:69) ~[na:na]
at java.base@17.0.7/sun.net.dns.ResolverConfigurationImpl.loadConfig(ResolverConfigurationImpl.java:136) ~[na:na]
at java.base@17.0.7/sun.net.dns.ResolverConfigurationImpl.nameservers(ResolverConfigurationImpl.java:159) ~[na:na]
at jdk.naming.dns@17.0.7/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory.serversForUrls(DnsContextFactory.java:149) ~[systemparam.exe:na]
at jdk.naming.dns@17.0.7/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory.getContext(DnsContextFactory.java:81) ~[systemparam.exe:na]
at jdk.naming.dns@17.0.7/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory.urlToContext(DnsContextFactory.java:120) ~[systemparam.exe:na]
at jdk.naming.dns@17.0.7/com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory.getInitialContext(DnsContextFactory.java:64) ~[systemparam.exe:na]
at java.naming@17.0.7/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:732) ~[systemparam.exe:na]
at java.naming@17.0.7/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305) ~[systemparam.exe:na]
at java.naming@17.0.7/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236) ~[systemparam.exe:na]
at java.naming@17.0.7/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208) ~[systemparam.exe:na]
at java.naming@17.0.7/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:130) ~[systemparam.exe:na]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DirContextUtils.addNameServers(DirContextUtils.java:49) ~[na:na]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.<clinit>(DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.java:55) ~[na:na]
53 common frames omitted
```

the app can run successfully with standard compile.

but when i use native compile, give me error above.

already tried adding

```
implementation 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:6.2.4.RELEASE'
```

but no success

Comment: Such errors are often caused by unconfigured reflection/resource/SPI access. Did you run the agent?

Comment: thank you for the insight. this is exactly what i am missing. 

the resources META-INF/native-image.properties

Answer (score 0):

finally found what i am missing.

i need to add args for META-INF/native-image/native-image.properties to initialize the ResolverConfigurationImpl at run time.

```
Args = --allow-incomplete-classpath \
   --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime \
   --initialize-at-run-time=sun.net.dns.ResolverConfigurationImpl
```

reference: [javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext fails on windows #4304](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/4304#issuecomment-1107528415)